# Cannot add table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've a piece of code for [adding/deleting table rows on button click using javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranrs/7AeDQ/1878/). My table having one dropdown menu with two textbox fields and one field for delete button. 
**This is my table.**
[image: table structure]

This is my HTML Code.

```
<table id="tbl" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Reg.Number</td>
            <td>Delete?</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <select id='group'>
                    <option value='0'>----------</option>
                 </select></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="sub" /></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="regno" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="del" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add more" onclick="insRow()"/>
```

**My Javascript code**

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('tbl').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('tbl');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;   
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is little bit strange, means, if I add one more dropdown list in the table , [the **"add"** function will not work](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranrs/7AeDQ/1879/). I tried everything, googled, read many articles but none of them helped me. Please help me to solve my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: you should see your browser's console for possible errors. In your second fiddle, `new_row.cells[1]` do not have any input element and your code will break at line `inp1.id` as `inp1` is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `.getElementsByTagName('input')` to `.getElementsByTagName('select')`
http://jsfiddle.net/2fk4L6fj/1/

Answer (score 2):

when you can't find the problem in your code , please press Button 'F12' and see what print in 'Console' then you will find it.

[image]